# Display a warning whenever invisible characters have been added to a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, design, error-message

As described [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert), Stack Exchange currently inserts invisible characters into long strings, so that they don't overflow their container.

This is fine, except that it breaks command lines, source code, and possibly URLs in a very strange way. For example, it took me a while to understand why `gconftool-2 --type string --set /org/gnome/desktop/w‌​m/preferences/action_‌​middle_click_titlebar "none"` results in the error `Error setting value: Bad key or directory name: "/org/gnome/desktop/w‌​m/preferences/action_‌​middle_click_titlebar": '\342' is not an ASCII character and thus isn't allowed in key names`. It's not obvious why it doesn't work unless you know about these invisible characters.

So if possible it would be great to have some kind of warning whenever text has been modified in a comment. Even better if there was a [copy] link next to it that allows copying the real content (even something rudimentary [like this](//stackoverflow.com/a/6055620/) would be an improvement).

For example:

> /!\ The content of this comment has been altered for display purposes. If you copy and paste it in a terminal or source code file it may not work. [Click here to copy the unmodified content]